# How are variables passed in php by default

Tags: php

I want to know how is value passed in php by default. Is it by reference or is it by value. 
I did a search and found that some say it's value only and some say its reference by default.
I understand its not a programming question but i need the answer for my recruitment interview.

Some say reference: 
    [Clarification of PHP manual; default values passed by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339162/clarification-of-php-manual-default-values-passed-by-reference)

Some say Value: [Are PHP Variables passed by value or by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879/php-variables-passed-by-value-or-by-reference)

Comment: To allow for more confusion, "the reference is passed by value" is another option, which I _think_ PHP uses.

Comment: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_YZIBWQr_yk) is a little YT video from SO member.

Answer (score 3):

Variables are passed by value. However, the value of a variable pointing to an object is the *address* of the object, not the object itself, so objects passed as method parameters are not copied; both the calling context and method will share the same object instance.